# CountrySelect form field, pre-populate with a country

Tags: intershop

How can I default to populating the Select drop down list with a value, in this case it would be the country U.S..  We've removed other countries from the list but users are still required to select the one option.

In addition to a default value, the dependent fields would need to be populated.  Currently in Intershop, selecting the country populates the State field.  I would like to default to U.S. and have the State field already populated on the initial request, sans ajax calls.

Comment: do you want to select country U.S. as the default dropdown value ?

Comment: In this case yes.  In other cases it would be a different value.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to modify some pipelines for this.

The webform it loads is based in the country code. Intershop gets the countrycode from the addressbo or as a parameter. See the ViewUserAccount-ChangeAddress : this pipeline is used in the ajax request to load the webform when u select a country. You could use the same logic to load the U.S webform (US) when the address has not been filled in yet.